# Postman Show Password checkbox missing

Tags: postman

In Postman, when choosing Authorization > Basic Auth it is possible to type username and password.

Below the password field there should be a checkbox "Show password" to choose if you want to display the password characters or the asterisks/stars if you want to hide what is being typed. In my case, the "Show password" checkbox is not being displayed and whenever I type a password it is displayed like in the print screen below. How to make the Show password checkbox apear so that I can hide the typed password?

[image]

Comment: This checkbox has been removed from the UI in the latest version, I would recommend using a variable (`{{...}}`) to store your sensitive values. The variables also have the masking feature when created as a secret type.

Comment: @Danny Dainton Thanks. It worked using a variable. Although I don't agree with removing the Show Password checkbox from the Authorization screen. I think it should be kept there. Then you choose if you want to use it or to use a variable. Anyway, thanks for the clarification. Feel free to add it as a response to the question and I'll accept it.